# Can I see a directory and its files and be prompted for authentication only when I get a file using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have the following file

```
/var/www/foo/foo-0.0.1.apk
```

and /var/www is DocumentRoot of one virtual host, available on http://bar.com

I want that

- P1- When I GET "http://bar.com", Then I see a link "foo"
- P2- When I GET "http://bar.com/foo", Then I see a link "foo-0.0.1.apk"
- P3- When I GET "http://bar.com/foo/foo-0.0.1.apk", Then I'm prompted to fill in login and password

I manage to do P2+P3 using /var/www/foo/.htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Private directory"
Require valid-user
```

But P1 is red

I enclosed above directive with a `<FilesMatch "\.apk$">`, but then P2 is red

Can I have all of, with htaccess ?

Comment: Why would P1 no longer work if you put the htaccess inside foo? That htaccess should not affect requests to bar.com/

Comment: Because I did not understand documentation properly